# Which method of df for chi square I have to apply either $(c-1)\cdot (r-1)$ or df$=n-1$?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study, chi-squared-test, p-value

[image]

I have 10 question, based on 5  Likert scale choices.
How do I find degree of freedom here in Chi square?
Some one says use $(r-1)\cdot (c-1)$ but I think it will apply on categorical data, my data is not that one.

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the self-study tag. Also this seems like a basic question so it might be closed.

Comment: What are you trying to find out?  Quite likely you don't need chi-square at all.

Comment: sir i only need how to find out df in question

Comment: What is your null hypothesis? What's your alternative? What underlying questions are you trying to answer from the data? (Note that your Likert-scale is ordered. It's generally unwise to ignore that)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say your data aren't categorical? Likert responses are [ordinal](/questions/tagged/ordinal). Maybe this is why @PeterFlom suggested you don't need $\chi^2$; it is more appropriate for nominal data. It can be applied here, but it wastes information. Furthermore, $\chi^2$ can only be applied to categorical data (continuous data must be binned to apply the test).

Anyway, if your intention is to apply a $\chi^2$ test of independence, you can find the appropriate choice of *df* by checking [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence) (or any textbook that covers it). It's a good habit to check references like these to make sure you're performing your analysis properly even when you're done doing homework and working in the "real world". That's why I'm choosing to point in the right direction rather than give you the answer: you'll find it easily if you take personal responsibility for finding it (this is also a matter of [site policy regarding self-study questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)).